# How to deploy multiple nodeJS application with different port

Tags: node.js, web, web-deployment

I'm rather new to NodeJS and I'd like to deploy the API and the application on the same server, which means same IP but on different ports.

From different search I saw it's possible but I don't know how. 
Can I use Restify for this redirection ?

Comment: Can your server respond to both API routes (ex `/api/*`) and front-end application routes (ex `/app/*`)? If not, and they're truly separate, you should consider running them on separate instances.

Comment: No the url would be like : server:3000 for the API and the server:3001 for the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this code app.listen(PORT HERE); on your two apps just define a different ports for each one.

For example

in App1 = app.listen(3000);
in App2 = app.listen(8000);

then to access each one is like :

App1 = http://localhost:3000 
App2 = http://localhost:8000

Comment: So once the port are defined in the application, i just need to deploy them both on my server and that would do the trick ?

Comment: sure, just place it in the server and then, run both at the same time